# Jquery Table plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a table plugin that does the following

1. Uses json and  html table as the datasource
2. supports pagination
3. can specify how many rows to show by the user(i.e user can change rows per page)
4. sorting of columns
5. searching (complex searching options is welcome)
6. free for commercial projects
7. dynamic addition/deletion
8. refresh option

Finally the **main requirement** is searching, sorting,pagination all needs to happen client side. No server interaction needed.

One more thing dont know if possible say i have 1000 records i want 100 to show up initially in 10 pages (i.e 10 each in 10 pages) only when user clicks on page 11 it fetches next 10 from server

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery DataTables are really pretty, and easy to use. http://www.datatables.net/ Lets you roll your own theme super easy. You can build from html or ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You can go check out http://flexigrid.info/ .  Its not a table exactly its a grid but you might be able to use it in the same way.  It accepts JSON and allows a lot of different ways to change display.

Comment: I take my above comment back.  I knew about the Jqgrid but I didnt watch the development on it that close.  That is really the way that I would go also.  Actually after looking through it again I'm going to change a lot of my things in favor of that

Answer (score 0):

this is what you're looking for: http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html